# How to revert files to a previous commit but keep other files to latest commit

Tags: git

Assume I have these commits (the letters are the hash number):

```
-a(initial commit)
-b(implemented feature request affected foo.php and bar.php)
-c(someone else's commit)
-d(someone experimented on foo.php/bar.php and forgot to discard changes)
-e(another commit)
-f(latest commit)
```

How do I change foo.php and bar.php to what it was during commit "c".
So far I've tried `git reset c` and `git reset --hard c` but it changes the whole repository instead.

Another method I tried so far is to make another clone of the repo and `reset --hard c`, then I manually copy pasted foo.php and bar.php to my working copy then I staged and pushed the changes to remote.

Answer (score 2):

Just revert the file to that old commit, and commit the changes.

```
git checkout <old_commit_id> file_path
```

For instance -

```
git checkout <hash_of_c> foo.php
git checkout <hash_of_c> bar.php
git add -u
git commit -m "revert foo and boo"
```